# How do I get the "Merry Christmas" achievement in DEFCON?

Tags: achievements, defcon

I have a feeling the new **Merry Christmas** achievement is going to become significant in a bit, and therefore I'd like to unlock it.

However, I have no idea how. The description doesn't help at all:

> Nuke Santa and thereby end Christmas for everyone, for ever more

The obvious (nuking the North Pole) hasn't worked, so how would I go about frying Santa?

Comment: Could you please wait for him to drop my presents before nuking him?

Comment: Okay, just to clarify, I'm not blind. Before the Steam event (when I asked this question), there was no Santa flying around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set your (computer's) date to December 24th and Santa will fly around the cities. Just wait until Defcon 1 and [nuke him](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ub2mqdmJBdc) when you can get a clear shot. Watch out for silos and aircraft as they can destroy your nukes.

Comment: That seems hard...

Comment: I didn't have to change my date. I just started it up today and he was there. I started the game with no AI, it was just me playing. So Santa was only landing in my cities. Then I just nuked right next to the one he was in. It was a very short trip for the nuke, so it was easy to time it.

Comment: @Byte56 I believe if you were trying to get the achievement prior to December 21st (when the objective was officially unveiled) you had to set the date to the 24th, but now you don't.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to start a game with *only one player* - no AIs. This will force Santa to travel between your own cities, so he'll stay close.

Start the game, and place silos relatively close to your own cities. Wait for DEFCON 1, set the game speed to the slowest speed, and wait for Santa to go to a city close to one of your silos. At that point, launch a nuke *directly* next to your own city - zoom in to help you choose the target. The nuke will move there quite quickly, and Santa will get caught in the blast before he has time to move to the next city.

Comment: This is the best tip in this thread, and worked great for me.

Answer (score 2):

As far as strategy goes for nuking Santa when he lands, it is a lot easier if you go into advanced options when you start a new game and make sure that each territory only has one city. This will limit where Santa can go and land, and makes it easier to predict where he is going next. The window of opportunity is small so it is almost essential to fire your nukes whilst Santa is travelling to the next city.

Comment: Note, I experienced crashes whenever I set the game to provide one city only to each player.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your computer's date to December 24th - than nuke Santa.

The easy way: Create a Human + Computer game, **where both of you are allied**. Position your subs and ships around 'your allay' territory, wait for DEFCON-1, wait for Santa to head for an unprotected city. Nuke.

Comment: you neither need to set the date anymore nor is an AI player necessary